# GitLab CI/CD Error while 'Pulling docker image'

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

## Problem

I am pretty new to the CI/CD realm, and I'm trying to figure out how to get my project deployed/tested with it. But I'm running into some pretty simple problems.

I am trying to specify a container in a GitLab instance to use, and the CI Jobs always seem to fail when pulling my docker image. The errors change based on the image value I use, and I'm not clear which one is closer to be correct. I'm leaning towards "invalid reference format" being the correct one, but am unclear.

I have already verified that the Project CI_TOKEN's are enabled (-/settings/ci_cd/TOKEN ACCESS -> CI_JOB_TOKEN)

I have a feeling this may have to do with the port being explicitly set in the image path. But I'm not sure?

#### Error (#1): "invalid reference format"

```yaml
default:
  image: gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@git.domain.tld:1234/path/to/<subgroup>/<project>/<container>:latest
```

```bash
Running with gitlab-runner 14.10.1 (f761588f) on <subgroup>-group nHMWApbD

00:00 - Resolving secrets
00:01 - Preparing the "docker" executor

Using Docker executor with image gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@git.domain.tld:1234/path/to/<subgroup>/<project>/<container>:latest ...
Pulling docker image gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@git.domain.tld:1234/path/to/<subgroup>/<project>/<container>:latest ...

WARNING: Failed to pull image with policy "always": 
   invalid reference format (manager.go:203:0s)
```

---

#### Error (#2): "requested access to the resource is denied"

```yaml
default:
  image: <project>/<container>:latest
```

```bash
Running with gitlab-runner 14.10.1 (f761588f) on <subgroup>-group nHMWApbD

00:00 - Resolving secrets
00:01 - Preparing the "docker" executor

Using Docker executor with image <project>/<container>:latest ...
Pulling docker image <project>/<container>:latest ...

WARNING: Failed to pull image with policy "always": 
   Error response from daemon: 
      pull access denied for <project>/<container>, 
      repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': 
   denied: requested access to the resource is denied (manager.go:203:0s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the second format with the following:

```yaml
job_name:
  image: $CI_REGISTRY/<project>/<container>:latest
```

More on [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/) and [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because as Gitlab official explain:

> If you use the **always** policy and the registry is not available, the job fails even if the desired image is cached locally.

solve method

After reading this guidance at GitLab website, I changed config.toml of gitlab-runner add a new line for pull_policy as following:

```
[[runners]]
  #....
  [runners.docker]
    pull_policy = ["if-not-present", "always"]
    #...
```

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

The issue was that b/c I was using a private registry, the job was having trouble authenticating to it. The solution was to create a variable in `Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables` with a key value of `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG`.

You can find the general format below, or you can look on your Local Host at `~/.docker/config.json` to find the file contents that serve as the value for `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG`.

##### NOTE

Since the entire config value can't be masked, I opted to use a $VARIABLE in place of the Base64 encoded value `bXlfdXNlcm5hbWU6bXlfcGFzc3dvcmQ=`. This is better practice security wise, since it allows you to mask the encoded form of your username:password in CI/CD logs.

##### .gitlab-ci.yml

```yaml
default:
  image: 
    name: registry.example.com:5000/path/to/<project>/<container>:tag
    entrypoint: [""]
```

##### Get the Base64 value of your username & password/token (from Local Host)

```yaml
# The use of printf (as opposed to echo) prevents encoding a newline in the password.
printf "my_username:my_password" | openssl base64 -A

# Example output to copy
bXlfdXNlcm5hbWU6bXlfcGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

##### Set Variable : DOCKER_AUTH_B64 (In GitLab, `Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables`)

```yaml
DOCKER_AUTH_B64: "bXlfdXNlcm5hbWU6bXlfcGFzc3dvcmQ="
```

##### Set Variable : DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG (In GitLab, `Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables`)

```yaml
{
    "auths": {
        "registry.example.com:5000": {
            "auth": "$DOCKER_AUTH_B64"
        }
    }
}
```

[Source](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#determine-your-docker_auth_config-data)